# Eigenvalues of a linear tranformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. An eigenvalue of T is a scalar $\lambda$ for which there exists a nonzero vector $x \in V$ such that $T(x)=\lambda x$

I need to show that the eigenvalues of T are precisely the solutions to the degree n polynomial $f(\lambda)= \det(T-\lambda Id)=0$

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Since $T(x)=\overline{T}x$ for [some matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) $\overline{T}$, letting $\lambda$ be an arbitrary scalar we have, for any vector $x\neq 0$,

$$\begin{align} 
T(x)=\lambda x&\iff \overline{T}x=\lambda x\\ 
&\iff \overline{T}x-\lambda x=0 \\ 
&\iff \overline{T}x-\lambda Ix=0 \\ &
\iff (\overline{T}-\lambda I)x=0\iff \det (\overline{T}-\lambda I)=0
\end{align}$$

The last equivalence is due to the fact that $x\neq 0$ and due to the theory of [homogeneous linear systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Solution_set_2).

Answer (score 1):

$T(v)=\lambda v \to$ $ T(v)-\lambda v =0 \to T(v)-\lambda I(v )=0$$$(T-\lambda I)(v)=0$$ beacuse  $v \neq 0$ (theorem : $Ax=0 $and $x\neq0$ iff $\det A=0$)then $$\det(T-\lambda I)(v)=0$$ notice inverse of  theorem is true you can easily conclude another direction

Comment: Be sure to cover both directions of the claim.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant functions detects when $\rm T - \lambda$ is invertible or not. As $\rm V$ has finite dimension, this means that $\rm T - \lambda$ has or hasn't a zero kernel.

And having non zero kernel means the existence of a non zero $x$ such that $(\mathrm T - \lambda) x = 0$.